# Same products displayed after certain pages of Magento categories

Tags: magento2.4

In Magento 2.4.x CE site noticed that category pages are displaying same content/products whenever a category has more than 2 pages. Basically pages 3, 4, and so on display page # 2 products. Tried clearing cache, re-index couple of times but still no clue.
Doesn't appear to be related to a theme as disabling or changing to other didn't fix the issue.
Products are not duplicated in the category based on the back-end data.

Any clues on how to debug this issue as I don't see any errors or messages in the logs.

Tested `rest/default_1/V1/products?searchCriteria` API endpoint with different category id's and results matches with admin panel numbers.

What other code or files I should check to debug this further or any other clues?

Doesn't appear to be indexing issue either, as I see same results even after running indexer:reindex couple of times.

Thanks

Comment: may be indexing issue? try to run `bin/magento indexer:reindex` command

Comment: Doesn't appear to the index issue, ran reindex too and it didn't resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting to Magento default search engine(Elasticsearch7) has resolved the issue. Need to see why a 3rd party vendor extension for Elasticsearch is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some customize on theme or code,

you can check these file, which is responsible for rendering category

```
Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml
```

also, check SQL by breaking out the debug on

```
Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct::getLoadedProductCollection()->getSelect()->__toString()
```

Comment: When I echoed _productCollection in the list.phtml, I see current page count only.  Any idea how to debug this in the server as I don't have working local environment?

Comment: Also I see following code in out of box ListProduct.php function. public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

        $categoryId = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $product->setData('category_id', $categoryId);
        }

        return $collection;
    }